# What is the easiest way to create log file in powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a code which modify user attribute in active directory. 
How can I modify the code, to see in a log file what changed? I would like to see too if there was an error or not. If was an error what was that.

The code:

```
$csvdata = Import-Csv $csv -Delimiter $delimiter -Encoding "UTF8"
ForEach-Object -InputObject $csvdata {
$params = @{Identity = $_.ObjectGUID}
$sn = $_.Surname.Trim()
$gn = $_.GivenName.Trim()
$Manager = $_.Manager
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Surname)) {
$params.Surname = $_.Surname
}
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Givenname)) {
$params.Givenname = $_.Givenname
}
Set-ADUser @params
}
```

Comment: in your case Transcript would do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transcript commands.

```
Start-Transcript
& ".\Script.ps1"
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: Write Start-Transcript at the moment when you want to start transcript.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following function for logging in a little script I made a while back, feel free to rip it up and abuse it!

```
function Write-Log {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline              =$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0
        )]
        [string[]]
            $Message,
        [string]
            $Level = "Informational"
    )
    if (!$loglocation)
    {
        write-error -Message 'No $LogLocation set.'
        break
    }

    $logarchive = split-path $loglocation
    $logarchive = $logarchive + "\Archive.log"
    $truedate = get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH:MM:ss

    if (test-path $loglocation)
    {
        if ((get-item $loglocation).length -ge 5242880)
        {
            "$truedate : Log exceeds 5MB, archiving and creating new log." | out-file -append -filepath $loglocation
            if (test-path $logArchive)
            {
                "$truedate : Log archive already exists, removing this log first before archiving current log." | out-file -append -filepath $loglocation
                get-item $logArchive | remove-item
            }
            get-childitem $loglocation | rename-item -NewName {"Archive.log"}
             "$truedate : New log created, old log archived." | out-file -append -filepath $loglocation
        }
    }
    "$truedate : $level - $message" | out-file -append -filepath $loglocation

}
```

You just need to set a variable in your script called `$loglocation` to the file path you want the log to save too, i.e. "C:\MyLogs" etc.  Then when you want to log something out to it, just use `write-log -Message "Whatever you are logging"`.